# VS IDE Add-ons for Control Guidelines

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a Visual Studio extension (similar to CnPack in Delphi) that adds guide lines to boundaries of flow of controls like the begin..end of if, while and for statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [CodeRush](https://www.devexpress.com/products/coderush/) It includes Structural Highlighting [image: img]
<sub>(source: [devexpress.com](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/i/StructuralHighlightingInCSharp.gif))</sub>